# TeamCity branch specification - Is there a way to exclude all sub folders?

Tags: git, teamcity

We are using hierarchical branch names so we have something like:

- master
- somework (branched off and merged into master)
- olderrelease/master
- olderrelease/someworkonolderrelease (branched off and merged into olderrelease/master)

We have set up TeamCity so that one set of build projects will build only git branches that are prefixed with `olderrelease/`. The branch specifications for these builds is `refs/heads/olderrelease/*`.

This has been working well for us. However, the problem is with TeamCity projects without a prefix, where we need to negate all sub-folders. For these we've been doing the following:

```
+:refs/heads/*
-:refs/heads/olderrelease/*
```

This does work but we've got quite a few sub-folders now so excluding them all with `-:` is getting very repetitive quickly, especially when you add tags into the mix too.

What I want to write is something like:

```
+:refs/heads/*
-:refs/heads/*/*
```

But this doesn't work. **Is there any way of including the root branches but excluding any nested branch "folders"?**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you modify your branch naming convention to be more easily parsed with a single wildcard, your option remains to singularly exclude the undesired branch(es) by using only one wildcard character per rule (emphasis added by me).

[TeamCity Branch Spec Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Configuringbranches)

> The syntax of the branch specification field is newline-delimited list of "+|-:branch_name" rules. "+:" rules include the matching branches into the list, the "-:" rules exclude the branches from the list.
>   **Each rule can have one optional "*" placeholder which matches one or more characters.**